# How to avoid custom url generation from joomla SH404SEF component?

Tags: joomla, duplicates

I have been using joomla Sh404sef component in my site,what is my problem is its generating two url for the same content so it produces the problem with google search engine as both url pointing to the same content.

Here is the examples of url generated from the component

**URL:**

1. http://www.mysite.com/page.html   -  Automatic URLS
2. http://www.mysite.com/page/       -  Custom URLS

When I go and do the purge url from the component option it eliminated the non html (.html) urls from the db but it creates the url again when we post new page etc.

any body come across this issue and could give a suggestion on it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find this is Joomla generating the url not SH404SEF.  It has a habit of generating extras especially where you have blog style views etc.  The way I get around this problem is 3 fold.

1. Create a solid menu structure (Now harder on Joomla2.5 where aliases are created with date/time).  This should take care of most issues.  Make sure you make unnecessary levels as noindex-nofollow
2. Use a 3rd party tool to mark secondary urls with a canonical tag.  Look at ITPMetaPro but many others are available.
3. Work in Webmaster Tools to remove urls from index after following step 1 & 2.